Get value from ElementTree using the full path
Let's say we have the following xml string
xml_string = '''
<Wikimedia>
  <projects>
    <project name="Wikipedia" launch="2001-01-05">
      <editions>
        <edition language="English">en.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="German">de.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="French">fr.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="Polish">pl.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="Spanish">es.wikipedia.org</edition>
      </editions>
    </project>
    <project name="Wiktionary" launch="2002-12-12">
      <editions>
        <edition language="English">en.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="French">fr.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="Vietnamese">vi.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="Turkish">tr.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="Spanish">es.wiktionary.org</edition>
      </editions>
    </project>
  </projects>
</Wikimedia>
'''

in an ElementTree
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml_string))
root = tree.getroot()

and I am trying to get its elemens using the full path search like
root.findall('Wikimedia/projects/project/editions/edition')
but this returns an empty list [].
How do I use the full path, including the starting node Wikimedia, to do this?

You are calling findall() on root, which is the Wikimedia element. It works if you simply remove Wikimedia/ from the path:
ed = root.findall('projects/project/editions/edition')

In addition, the code that creates the root object can be simplified. Just use
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

